# Number of matchings in a bipartite graph having missing edges

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, matching, assignment-problem

Suppose we have a bipartite graph with $N$ vertices on either side.
In the full bipartite graph, the number of edges is $N^2$ and the number of possible matchings (i.e. assignments) is $N!$.

Now suppose a few known edges ($O(1)$ edges) are missing from the full bipartite graph.

How can we find the number of matchings?

Is there a closed formula?

Comment: Do you mean that we have the parts, $A$ and $B$, so the graph is $G=(V,E)$, where $V=A \cup B$ and $E \subseteq \{\{a,b\}| a \in A, b \in B\}$? And do we know which $O(1)$ edges are missing? And is your question, “Is there a formula for the number of matchings under those conditions?”

Comment: For the 1st part of your question : Yes, as it is a bipartite graph. 
2nd part : Yes, we know which edges are missing. I have edited the question to make it more explicit. 
3rd part : Yes, I wish to know if we can get to know how many distinct matchings are  possible in the bipartite graph having known missing edges.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is #P-hard, which means it is believed that there is no efficient algorithm for this problem.

See [Counting and finding all perfect/maximum matchings in general graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19924/755) and [Number of Matchings in a Bipartite](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19275/755).

When the number of missing edges is small,   e.g., a fixed constant, there are algorithms whose running time  is polynomial  in $N$ (but exponential in the number  of missing edges), via the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: I guess the keyword here is “few” missing edges. The graph is $K_{n,n}$ for a fixed number of missing edges, the problem is definitely in P.

Comment: @AspiringMat, good point, thank you.  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AspiringMat yes you are right. It is known to me which edges are missing. And then, I would like to know the number of matchings possible in the bipartite graph.

Comment: @D.W. The suggested links are not much helpful. My question is very straightforward - is there a formula to find the number of matchings possible in a bipartite graph with known missing edges ?

Comment: @AspiringMat  I would like to present a quick example. Say, in a bipartite graph having 3 vertices on either side, suppose we know that 3 edges are missing. If the 3 missing edges are towards one particular vertex on right side of the graph, then we won't have any feasible matching. But of the 3 missing edges are distributed unevenly, then there will be some number of feasible matchings. Can I use a formula to compute the number of matchings ?

Comment: @akhil, There is an algorithm, as I explained in my answer.  There is unlikely to be a simple formula.  Once an algorithm is known, it seems to me that answers the question from the perspective of computer science.  If that is not satisfactory, it is possible that your question might be one of mathematics rather than of computer science.

Comment: @D.W. Sorry to differ but the suggested algorithms do not solve the problem stated in the question. The suggested algorithms do not consider the known missing edges in the bipartite graph. They assume that a vertex, say on the left side of the bipartite graph connects to all other vertices on the other side of the bipartite graph.

Comment: @akhil, No, they don't assume that.  See especially the last paragraph  of my answer.

Comment: @D.W. In the last para, you have not mentioned any specific algorithm. There must be a specific well-known algorithm to solve the problem. I could not find it on internet search. If you are aware of any algorithm (as claimed in your last para), please help me by specifying it explicitly.